# Crystal Scepter with Gangplanks passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

I cannot find anywhere if gangplanks passive poison on-hit effect (which does magic damage) works with Rylai's Crystal Scepter.

I know this isn't viable in most instances, but I found myself wanting to get it as a last item in an ARAM game, but didn't because I assumed it didn't work. However it DOES work with brands passive (magic damage over-time as well), so now I am wondering if I was incorrect in thinking that it would not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rylai's Crystal Scepter's slow does not apply from the damage of Grog-Soaked Blade. (Note that it *does* apply from the damage of Cannon Barrage, but not Parrrley.)

(Source: In-game testing.)

Comment: Well that is pretty inconsistent from Riot. But thanks for the testing Rilgon. :)

Comment: It is consistent: Parrrley and Grog Soaked Blade apply on-hit effects which means they count as basic attacks. Basic attacks don't trigger Rylai's, only abilities do. Cannon Barrage doesn't trigger on an attack and doesn't apply on-hit effects, so it's an ability. Abilities trigger Rylai's.

Comment: @dbemerlin But when it is consistent, why does it work with Brands passive DoT (as Joseph mentioned)?

Comment: @PatrickStalder I believe that may have to do with the fact that Brand's passive is triggered from abilities, but Grog-Soaked Blade is not.

Comment: It works with Brands' passive because his passive IS an ability and does not proc on-hit effects.